# Where can I found documentation about page lifecycle events?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, page-lifecycle, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am using cdp (https://github.com/mafredri/cdp) in order to use devtools protocol to generate a pdf of a page. But first I need to know when the page is completely loaded. I found that the networkIdle event can help me to know when this occurs. But, I have troubles because the networkIdle event sometimes fired twice. Then I need to know when this one is fired

Comment: [Page Lifecycle API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api).

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts for what you're looking for.

First of all, the reason the event is fired twice. When a new tab (*target*) is created, the first page it loads is **about:blank**. You get lifecycle events for this page as well. The second time the load event is fired is the one you're looking for (if you're using [Page.lifecycleEvent](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#event-lifecycleEvent)).

Now, to handle the second matter - there are also other events you can use. The basic one for page loading is [Page.loadEventFired](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#event-loadEventFired), which, as far as I recall, will only be fired for the actual page (but I could be wrong about this one).

Important note: If you're using lifecycle events, they are fired for each frame separately, meaning that the main frame might finish loading before the sub frames are loaded. `Page.loadEventFired` has a different behavior and waits for all frames to fire their load event.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good article on the [page lifecycle api](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api#developer-recommendations-for-each-state).

Another possible solution could be:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    run the screenshot code...
  }
}
```